# How to add event keydown in mootools

Tags: events, mootools, keydown

Please, help me!
This is my code:

```js
this.rez[str].each(
                function(v){
                    var li = new Element('li', {
                        'html': v[1],
                        'cl_id': v[0],
                        styles: {
                            backgroundColor: 'white',
                        },
                        events: {
                            'mousemove': function(){this.focus(li)}.bind(this),
                            'click' : function(){
                                alert('click);
                            }.bind(this),
                            'keydown' : function(event){
                                    alert('keydown');
                            }.bind(this)
                        }
                    }).inject(this.blockul);
                }, this
            );
```

The event "keydown" doed not work. How to fix it?

Comment: Can you make  example of your problemin jsFiddle? It works for me... http://jsfiddle.net/01fo39de/

Comment: you are binding a keydown event to a non input element. this won't work unless it has focus +/or child input/textarea elements.